# Laravel 8 custom foreign name with foreignId()

Tags: laravel-7

Laravel 7 introduced a shorter version of defining foreign keys with a function `foreignId`, but I can't find option to provide a custom name for that foreign ID.

In "old" way, we would wrote:

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
$table->foreign('user_id', 'custom_foreign_key_name')->references('id')->on('users');
```

New way:

```
$table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained();
```

But how to provide a "custom_foreign_key_name" in new way? Is it even possible?

Comment: Sadly...the only way I can get it working is with the "old" way. Laravel 8

Answer (score 3):

example- You can add your table name inside constrained() :

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('tutor_payouts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('tutor_id')->constrained('users');
        $table->foreignId('fee_id')->constrained();
        $table->dateTime('payout_date');
        $table->double('payout_amount', 8, 2);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Reference: [https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints][1]

If your table name does not match Laravel's conventions, you may specify the table name by passing it as an argument to the constrained method:

```
Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained('users');
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I was not asking for table name, I was asking on how to create custom name for foreign key, because sometimes those keys can get really long and are rejected by MySQL. In old way I was providing custom foreign key name.

Comment: Hi i have exactly the same problem, and cant find any solution sadly

Comment: Confirmed, only the "old way" supports defining keys.